# Using sed to replace \ characters in file

Tags: sed

I've got a file containing something like this:

```
command_command2="value" command3="\\value\value2"
```

I need to replace all \ with .

When using sed:

```
sed -i 's/\/./g' $old > $new
```

i get an error message:

```
 - sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

Any leads?

Comment: You have to escape your backslash: `sed -e 's/\\/./' <$old >$new`

Comment: @F.Hauri Almost there - I need to replace all \ characters with .

Comment: Once you added `g` switch to `s` command, I **strongly** recommand you to read `info sed`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that works. You can use `|` as well. Less confusing than `/` in this case.

```
  line="command_command2=\"value\" command3=\"\\value\value2\""
  ]$ echo $line | sed 's|\\|.|g'
  command_command2="value" command3=".value.value2"
```